# Why the execution time is different for following SQL Server code?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function, time, execution

Note: Neglect the logic inside `GO`...........`GO`, focus on only `Line 1` and `Line N`

```
SELECT DATENAME(NANOSECOND, GETDATE()) --Line 1

GO
BEGIN
    DECLARE @t1 NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @datetime1 DATETIME = '12-23-35';
    DECLARE @time1 TIME(4) = '11:10:05.1234';
    DECLARE @time2 TIME(5) = '11:10:05.12345';
    DECLARE @datetime2 DATETIME;

    SET @datetime2 = @datetime1
    SET @datetime2 = @time1

    DECLARE @datetime3 DATETIME = @time2
    DECLARE @datetime4 SMALLDATETIME = @time1

    IF @datetime1 = @datetime2
        PRINT 'True'
    ELSE
        PRINT 'False'

    IF @datetime2 = @datetime3
        PRINT 'True'
    ELSE
        PRINT 'False'

    IF @datetime3 = @datetime4
        PRINT 'True'
    ELSE
        PRINT 'False'

    SELECT @datetime1 AS 'datetime1'
        ,@datetime2 AS 'datetimevar2'
        ,@datetime3 AS 'datetimevar3'
        ,@datetime4 AS 'datetimevar4'
END
GO

SELECT DATENAME(NANOSECOND, GETDATE()) --Line N
```

---

Question:
For the above code, at each new execution Difference between 
`Line N` Result - `Line1` Result is not same.
Why is this So?

Comment: You expect that the same code takes exactly the same time each time you execute it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of reasons, bu the most simple one is that the computer is multitasking, i.e. doing many things at the same time. So, it depends on what else it's doing.

Believe me, you should not worry about this kind of things. Why is it important? You have to worry about important differences in execution times when you find a performance problem. Worrying about this is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You get different values because `GETDATE()` returns the current date and time, and time has elapsed between the execution of line 1 and line n, You can simplify your query massively and get the same result:

```
SELECT TOP 1 DATENAME(NANOSECOND, GETDATE()) --Line 1
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.01';
SELECT TOP 1 DATENAME(NANOSECOND, GETDATE()) --Line N
```

Having `TOP 1` in there allows you get the execution plan out, in which you will see that for each statement, there is the following block:

[image]

is repeated for each statement. `GETDATE()` is a runtime constant, but *can* be evaluated more than once in the same statement and is certainly evaluated more than once for multiple statements.